# Trying to toggleClass after ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Im trying to toggle between 2 classes after an ajax call but i get this error:

```
TypeError: toggleButton.children(...)[0].toggleClass is not a function
```

This is my code

```
console.log(toggleButton.children()['0']);
toggleButton.children()['0'].toggleClass('fa-check fa-times');
```

This is the element i am trying to toggle how it shows in the console

```
<i class="fas fa-times" style="color:red">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing a jQuery object by index (eg. `children()[0]`) returns the underlying Element object, not a jQuery object, hence `toggleClass()` is undefined.

To fix this you can use jQuery's methods instead of `[0]`. In this case, either `first()` or `eq(0)` will work:

```
toggleButton.children().first().toggleClass('fa-check fa-times');
```

Comment: Just found this works to    .find(">:first-child")  but your answer works also. Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just for reference there's also `:nth-child()`, `:first-child` and `:first()` :)